# haskell : parse error on Set [Int]

Tags: list, haskell, set

I am trying to create a set of lists of int :

```
récolte :: Arbre -> Set [Int]
```

but I get a parser error while trying to implement the function récolte.
The line where the error consist of taking the "unions" of 3 lists; each list contains one set of [Int].

here is the code:

```
récolte :: Arbre -> Set [Int]
récolte a =
  let fun :: Arbre -> [Int] -> Set [Int]
      --retourner essai res+2 enf
      fun (Feuille 1 [])  _ =  singleton [1]
      --les branches 0 sont des partitions en 2  => que 2 enfants
      fun (Branche 0 ys@(y1:y2:[])) acc =
--->  unions ( [singleton ([valeur y  | y <- ys] ++ acc) ++
--->    [fun y1 (acc ++ [valeur y2] )] ++
--->    [fun y2 (acc ++ [valeur y1] )])
      fun (Branche _ ys) acc = unions [fun y acc  | y <- ys]  --branche i ys
      listWithDoubles = fun a [] -- enlever doublons
  in map (\liste -> sort liste ) listWithDoubles
```

do you see a parser error? I don't think it is necessary to understand the meaning of this function to debug it, althought I know it's meaning but can't see the error!

I thought the re is maybe something to add : the set of lists of int should know how to order lists of ints (with compare) but I'm not sure about it, and it should not produce a parser error...

maybe you will be able to help me!

EDIT :

resolved! there were 2 errors : one of indentation unions was at the same column as the declaration of fun, and after "acc" there must be a closing bracket. 
thanks anyway, it is not easy to solve an error without knowing what it does!

Comment: Do they still make compilers that say "hi there, you have a syntax error, bye"? Upgrade to GHC, you will have at least a line number and an offending token.

Comment: I wonder if it may be just the lack of indentation of `unions` under `fun (Branche 0 …`.

Comment: Note that the `unions ...`  lines _must_ be indented more than the `fun (Branche ...` line. Otherwise, `unions ...` seems to start a definition of a new function named `union`, and the parser gets confused.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to use `\liste -> sort liste`. Thanks to the eta law, you can simply use `sort` instead -- e.g. `map sort listWithDoubles`.

Comment: @n.m. In the lolcode programming language, "kthxbye" is a language construct IIRC, so that error style would be completely idiomatic, I guess ;-)

Comment: @chi: "U haz syntax error, fix plz, kthxbye!"

Comment: I will summarily vote to close all questions about compiler errors that do not include the compiler error message.